# Python tar package doesn't contain package files

Tags: python, distutils

This is my setup file :

```
from setuptools import setup ,find_packages
setup ( 
    name='KissDownloader',
    version='2',
    description = 'A kisscartoon/kissanime downloader' ,
    packages=find_packages(where='kissdownloader'),
    author='Vriska',
    author_email='xyz@gmail.com',
    install_requires = ['bs4','cfscrape','requests'],
    package_data={'data' : ['C:\Program Files\PhantomJS\phantomjs.exe']},
    )
```

In the folder where I have setup.py there another folder called kissdownloader , it contains 3 .py files . I run python setup.py sdist , everything seems to go smoothly but for that when I open my tar zip , I don't find my .py programs .

Comment: just a guess, change the "packages=find_packages(where='kissdownloader')," to "packages=['KissDownloader'],"

Comment: i think that your problem is that you mentioned the folder of your package, the find_package is looking for packages which are basically inside a folder, so i'm guessing that you can also do the following: "packages=find_packages(where='.'),"

Comment: @MKUltra Thanks ! That did the trick ! Hey , not related but any idea how I can get PhantomJS.exe to install in C:\\Program Files\PhantomJS\phantomjs.exe  ? Thanks , also , post this as the answer and I'll select it . Who knows , it might help someone .

Comment: Glad it works, regarding your question, check [this blog](https://blog.niteoweb.com/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py/) you can use this technique to execute your own code and in your case to copy or silent install the phantomjs